# Spring Hello World - Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: spring

I am new to SpringFramework, and I downloaded the tutorial on tutorialPoint, set up Eclipse with (Java SE8) and downloaded SpringFrameWork 4.3.8 to run the HelloWorld example.  I had done a extensive search on this problem but none of the solutions posted on the internet solves my problem.

My Beans.xml is as follow:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd"> 

<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.spring.SpringHello">
 <property name="message" value="Hello Spring World!" />
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Below are the error message when executed:

> Apr 20, 2017 11:14:59 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>
> INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d6d97: startup date [Thu Apr 20 11:14:59 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>
> Apr 20, 2017 11:14:59 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>
> INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 134; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ...

Comment: If you are doing a Spring tutorial for Spring 4+, I think you should find one that uses code-only bean declaration, and not XML files. I have used Spring for the past 10 years, but I have not used XML defined beans for the last 4 years.

Comment: Klaus Groenbaek - Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `www.` to your xmlns

change

```
xmlns="http://springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

to

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

Comment: Oooh! I checked the file a million times but did not spot the missing www. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No worries. I use Spring Tool Suite (eclipse based). It generates the spring xml file. I did a diff with your file using kdiff3. I probably would not have spotted it without kdiff3. You should probably get STS or install a plug-in to help manage spring with eclipse.

Comment: Titi - I would like to do everything manually when I start to learn something :). Definitely will use the Tool Suite when developing more seriously with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Update your XML file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans             
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd         
                       ">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.spring.SpringHello">
        <property name="message" value="Hello Spring World!" />
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Initialize Spring Application through [SpringInitializr](https://start.spring.io/)

After Downloading .zip file, extract it, goto directory and just type

> mvn spring-boot:run

It will Boot your spring application.